# Uniqueness of Laurent Series in $|z| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

Let $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_i| < \infty$.

Then if $ |z| \le 1$  $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|a_iz^i| < \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|a_i| < \infty$ and similarly:

If $ |z| \ge 1$  $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_{-i}z^{-i}| < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_{-i}| < \infty$

Therefore: we have absolute convergence of $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_iz^i$ if $|z| = 1$

Now suppose that we have $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_iz^i = 1$ for all $|z| = 1$

**My question:** Can we say that by uniqueness of Laurent series that: $a_0= 1$ and $a_i = 0$ if $i\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Under that hypothesis, I cannot see that the Laurent series will converge in an annulus. I'd just integrate $z^kf(z)$ about the unit circle.

Comment: This is exactly the result on uniqueness of Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @AnginaSeng so I just need to integrate the principal part, and derivate de positive part right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment! But I don´t know why there is a relation with fourier series under the hypothesis

Comment: @user128422 Just write $z=e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ to see the relation with Fourier series.

Comment: @user128422 I you just write $z$ as $e^{it}$ then the question becomes whether $\sum_k |a_k|<\infty$ and $\sum a_ke^{itk} =1$  for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$ implies $a_0=1$ and $a_k=0$ for $k \neq 0$. This is true and it is quite basic from theory of FS.